# Unallocated amount in item line

Tags: java

I have a question regarding how to allocate a given amount to line of items. 
Basic I have this kind of simple code. How do I reconcile each line item so that the balance amount will be zero if the paid amount is sufficient. If not, the last item will has a balance to pay. Any suggestion or good algorithm on this?
Thanks. The output is in the comment.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    BigDecimal paidAmount = BigDecimal.valueOf(200);
    List<Item> items = initializeItems();
    calculateItemBalanceAmount(paidAmount, items);
    displayItems(items);
}

private static void calculateItemBalanceAmount(BigDecimal paidAmount, List<Item> items) {
    for (Item item : items) {
        if (paidAmount.compareTo(item.getTotalOwed()) > 0) {
            item.setTotalPaid(item.getTotalOwed());
            item.setBalance(item.getTotalOwed().subtract(item.getTotalPaid()));
        } else {
            item.setTotalPaid(paidAmount);
            item.setBalance(paidAmount.subtract(item.getTotalOwed()));
            break;   // Ugly
        }
    }
}

protected static List<Item> initializeItems() {
    List<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();
    Item item = new Item(BigDecimal.valueOf(1000));
    items.add(item);
    item = new Item(BigDecimal.valueOf(1000));
    items.add(item);
    item = new Item(BigDecimal.valueOf(1000));
    items.add(item);
    return items;
}

protected static void displayItems(List<Item> items) {
    System.out.print(StringUtils.rightPad("Total Owed", 15));
    System.out.print(StringUtils.rightPad("Paid", 15));
    System.out.print(StringUtils.rightPad("Balance to be paid", 15));
    System.out.println();
    for (Item i : items) {
        System.out.print(StringUtils.rightPad(i.getTotalOwed().toString(), 15));
        System.out.print(StringUtils.rightPad(i.getTotalPaid().toString(), 15));
        System.out.print(StringUtils.rightPad(i.getBalance().toString(), 15));
        System.out.println();
    }
}

private static class Item {
    private BigDecimal totalOwed = BigDecimal.ZERO;
    private BigDecimal totalPaid = BigDecimal.ZERO;
    private BigDecimal balance = BigDecimal.ZERO;

    public Item(BigDecimal totalOwed) {
        this.totalOwed = totalOwed;
    }

    public BigDecimal getTotalOwed() {
        return totalOwed;
    }

    public void setTotalOwed(BigDecimal totalAmount) {
        this.totalOwed = totalAmount;
    }

    public BigDecimal getBalance() {
        return balance;
    }

    public void setBalance(BigDecimal balance) {
        this.balance = balance;
    }

    public BigDecimal getTotalPaid() {
        return totalPaid;
    }

    public void setTotalPaid(BigDecimal totalPaid) {
        this.totalPaid = totalPaid;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are getting remainder, that is what you want to know, right? What is your question then?

Comment: @NamanGala Thanks for the code. But my question is how do you calculate each item balance? Is there any good algorithm to use? Given user pays 3000, then each line item will has 0 as balance.

Each line will show **total to pay** , **balance**

Comment: For your requirement, you could create a class as a cart, in which you could store your list and other variables like balance, remainder, total. And you could expose a method to add amount in list and this method will internally update other variables.

Comment: I have updated my answer. I feel that it is a really ugly implementation and maybe I can get any advice to do it properly.

Comment: You could refer this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21356182/shopping-cart-program). You can implement that way.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question then you want the remaining balance which user has to pay.

So in your code you are getting remainder as how much money user has in account. When I run your code, I am getting negative remainder as -200.

If I look at the expected value in `Balance` i.e. 200. So basically, you just want that if remainder is negative, then that much amount is remaining as a balance.

After `for loop` you can add below code.

```
BigDecimal balance = BigDecimal.valueOf(0);;
if (remainder.signum() == -1) {
    balance = remainder.negate();
    System.out.println("Balance : " + balance);
}
```

Comment: You could refer this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21356182/shopping-cart-program).